# How to externally configure logging in a Flex app?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, logging

I was wondering what people are using for externally configuring logging in a Flex app. Are there any ready baked solutions out there, similar to Log4J's configuration via properties files for instance?

If there are, do these work directly with the Flex logging API or are they part of a separate logging library?

Answer (score 0):

yes there is a library that comes with flex mx.logging using this u can add logging functionality in your application both in Adobe Air and Adobe Flex. hope i answered your question :)

Regards,